# JQuery link in Shareboot masterpage

Tags: jquery, master-page

I am building and testing a local sharepoint site using Shareboot but can't get my link to JQuery in the Shareboot master page working.  When I add it I'm only getting a blank page returned.  I take my link out and the page is working again.

Here is the code I'm using and I'm placing this just before the `</head>` in the masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="http://2008-sp-2013-jc/sites/labeller/Style%20Library/jquery-min.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

Anyone got any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Additional: The file location is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try it as just a normal script tag first and see if that works? ScriptLink refers to the server file system I believe.

Comment: Brilliant.  I never thought that would work which is why I didn't try it.  I Googled how to add the link in and got the above ... sometimes Google is not your friend.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptLink directives will always look in the /_LAYOUTS/1033 directory for your script. If you are not deploying the files to the file system and instead using the Style Library, you need to use the standard `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://2008-sp-2013-jc/sites/labeller/Style%20Library/jquery-min.js"></script>
```

> With ScriptLink you have the ability to specify when you want the
>   script to load asynchronously or after the after the page is ready.
>   The ScriptLink will always look in /_LAYOUTS/1033 for the scripts.

http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/